# 'monerod status' mining hash rate

Tags: monerod, cpu-mining, mining, hashrate

Does the **monerod status** command show the mining hash rate per thread or in total ?

eg

```
Height: 1461927/1461927 (100.0%) on mainnet, mining at 50 H/s, net hash
381.26 MH/s, v6, up to date, 9(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 20m 36s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mining at 50 H/s` message indicates your total mining hash rate.